# How to get hyperlinks on image on mouse hover?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, css, sql-server-2008, join

I am making a eCommerce online shopping website.
I want the look of my my page just like that of flipkart.
Like this

[image: Image of Main Category]

[image: And on mouse hower all the hyper link of all subcategories are shown]

Image of Main Category

And on mouse hower all the hyper link of all subcategories are shown

My tables are

```
ProductCategory
Column Name  Data Type  Constraint
CategoryID   Varchar(20)    Primary key
CategoryName Varchar(100)   Unique key
Description  Varchar(1000)  


ProductSubCategory
Column Name     Data Type   Constraint
SubCategoryID   Int    Auto increment , Primary key
SubCategoryName Varchar(100)    
Description     Varchar(1000)   
CategoryID      Varchar(20) Foreign key with Product Category

ProductSubCategory2
Column Name         Data Type   Constraint
SubCategory2ID       Int    Auto increment , Primary key
SubCategory2Name    Varchar(100)    
Description         Varchar(1000)   
SubCategoryID        Varchar(20)    Foreign key with Product SubCategory

CompanyInfo

Column Name Data Type   Constraint
CompanyID   Varchar(20) Primary key
CompanyName Varchar(100)    Unique key
Description Varchar(1000)
```

```
ProductInfo
Column Name Data Type   Constraint
ProductID   Int Primary key , auto increment
ProductName Varchar(100)    
SubCategory2ID  Int Foreign key with ProductSubCategory
CompanyID   Varchar(20) Foreign key with CompanyInfo
Price   Float   
Quantity    Int 
Description Varchar(1000)
```

So Please help me to make a join query to display the onle a single image for each Category and on mouse over it shows the hyperlinks of subcategory
Please help me in getting image from database and the applying css or javaquery for that image

Comment: Study their CSS and JS file.

Comment: You are asking us to do it for you? No way, show some effort first. You may have a lot of learning to do before you even start that project.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what your looking for http://webdesign.about.com/od/dhtml/a/aadhtmlmenus.htm enables you to use the :hover pseudo class to display a menu in which you can have your subcategories.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

For each category thumb, include a div containing all the hyperlinks of the subcategories, give it a `position: absolute` and set the default `display:none`.

Then on hover (you can use either css or jquery) change the css property to `display: block`.

Additionally, depending on your design structure, you might also want to include a higher css `z-index` property for the hyperlink div